# Is it possible to log every http request in an android application? ( By recompiling & Without sniffing )

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, smali, apktool

**Important: i do not wish to log using packet logger / proxy / etc - for various reasons**

I have an application that i want to log every request that goes through it by decompile / recompiling the application

```
invoke-static {v0, v2}, Landroid/util/Log;->v(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

where v2 has the post string.

Now  basically, since the program is seriously large, i cannot go over the reqyests one by one and log every http request, is it possible to log them all?

Comment: It seems that you want to track someone else's endpoints.

Comment: ...that use SSL with cert pinning :D